# Navigation drawer with sliding tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am using [bradley's](https://github.com/BradleyRL/NavDrawerExampleAppCompat-v7) `navigation drawer` for displaying options in a `listAdapter`. Now I want to change the layout and add sliding tabs in the `appCompatActionBar`. The attached image is what I want to achieve.

Can someone provide a tutorial link or tell me how should I modify the actionbar to draw such layout?

[image]

Comment: Please look at any new tutorial, documentation and Android development blog. This is asked all the time. Please see this from a Google developer: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Use google's new support library for material design. You can easily achive it by TabLayout and ViewPager and NavigationView for navigation drawer here is the link
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: Thank you guys.. Appreciate the help. I know how to take things on from here.